# Como hacer una rand con palabras?

Tags: php

Quiero hacer como una rand pero de palabras, que entre las palabras que haya dentro de los parentesis elija un aleatoriamente. No se como hacerlo, necesito ayuda, gracias

```
$jugador=rand("&#x1F91B","&#x1F91A","$&#x1F596");
print "  <p>{$jugador}</p>\n";
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no generas un número aleatorio, lo limitas al rango **1-n** o **0-(n - 1)** y usas ese número para acceder a un elemento de un arreglo (con strings o lo que desees)?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo podrias hacer usando [array_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-rand.php). Por lo que podrias dejar tu codigo asi:

```
$jugadores = array("&#x1F91B","&#x1F91A","$&#x1F596"); // creamos el array con los jugadores
$jugador = $jugadores[array_rand($jugadores)]; // usamos array_rand para seleccionar un indice aleatorio del array y despues accedemos a ese indice

print "  <p>{$jugador}</p>\n"; // mostramos el resultado
```